# Exclude file from stylecop checking

Tags: cruisecontrol.net, nant, stylecop

I want to exclude /Properties/AssemblyInfo.cs from stylecop checking.
Can we do that?
the problem is that i have integrated stylecop with nant. In nant i am stamping product version so the information from Assembly info changes and it gives warning in nant email. I am using stylecopcmd 
for nant integration.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to do this. The recommended method is with [file lists](http://stylecop.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Using%20File%20Lists&referringTitle=Documentation). Here is an example:

```
<StyleCopSettings Version="4.3">
  <SourceFileList>
    <SourceFile>AssemblyInfo.cs</SourceFile>
    <Settings>
    <GlobalSettings>
      <BooleanProperty Name="RulesEnabledByDefault">False</BooleanProperty>
    </GlobalSettings>
    </Settings>
  </SourceFileList>
</StyleCopSettings>
```

Alternatively you can use the `ExcludeFromStyleCop` setting in the project file as documented [here](http://stylecop.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Using%20StyleCop%20on%20Legacy%20Projects&referringTitle=Documentation):

```
<Compile Include="AssemblyInfo.cs"> 
  <ExcludeFromStyleCop>true</ExcludeFromStyleCop> 
</Compile>
```